# How to Position wxPython slider control

Tags: wxpython, slider

I'm not having any luck at setting the horizontal position of wxPythons slider controls. In all my tests setting the horizontal position has no effect on the placement of the control.
Can any one tell me what I'm missing?
Thanks

Here's what I've tried:

```
    import wx 

    class SliderFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Slider Example', size=(400, 600))
            panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
            self.count = 0
            hslider1 = wx.Slider(panel, 100, 25, 1, 100, pos=(10, 10),
                    size=(250, -1),
                    style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS )
            hslider1.SetTickFreq(5, 1)

            hslider2 = wx.Slider(panel, 100, 25, 1, 100, pos=(100, 330),
                    size=(250, -1),
                    style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS )
            hslider2.SetTickFreq(5, 1)


            vslider1 = wx.Slider(panel, 100, 25, 1, 100, pos=(15, 70),
                    size=(-1, 250),
                    style=wx.SL_VERTICAL | wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS )
            vslider1.SetTickFreq(20, 1)



    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = SliderFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's odd.  An obvious work around is to put the slider in a panel that you can position (below), or use sizers.  Also, note that the error goes away if you use

```
    p2 = wx.Panel(panel, -1, size=(250, 100), pos=(100,330))
    hslider2 = wx.Slider(p2, -1, 27, 0, 100,
            size=(250, -1),
            style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS )
    hslider2.SetTickFreq(5, 1)
```

It also works to use `SetDimensions`, like this:

```
    hslider2 = wx.Slider(panel, -1, 27, 0, 100,
            style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS )
    hslider2.SetTickFreq(5, 1)
    hslider2.SetDimensions(100, 330, 250, -1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you comment but the problem is not the value of the slider its the fact that, for the position tuple (X,Y) the X value is ignored. hslider1 should be at pos=(10,10) hslider2 pos=(100,30) yet both align at the far left of the window. The vertical slider-vslider1 responds correctly to X position changes.

Comment: I see.  I fixed my answer.  It does seem like some sort of a bug.

Comment: Again thanks for the tip to put the slider in a panel its a solution, but doesn't it seem odd that the horizontal sliders x-position is ignored yet the vertical sliders x position is used??

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Also, btw, it seems to have something to do with the `-1` in `size=(250,-1)`, since if that's removed the problem goes away too.  I usually use sizers, so I'm not an expert on what's going on with the `-1` thing though.

Comment: Thanks for you help Tom. I'll go with your answer and post the question on the wxPython group to see if its a bug.